# Cross product determinant's matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

The cross product $a \times b$ can be represented by the determinant

$$\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b}= \begin{vmatrix}
\mathbf{i} & \mathbf{j} & \mathbf{k} \\
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \\
\end{vmatrix}.$$

Does the *matrix* whose determinant is this have any significance?

Comment: It seems doubtful, given that it's only a matrix in a certain formal sense, with different elements in the first row than in the second and third rows. One might expect a matrix with further significance to correspond to some linear transformation, but for that it would have to be a "proper" matrix.

Comment: I agree with joriki that it is mainly just a helpful mnemonic device to remember how to compute the product, and not a real matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can let the matrix act by ordinary matrix multiplication on ordinary vectors in three-dimensional space.

This will transform a vector in a triple containing the original vector and the lengths of the two projections on $a$ and $b$.

While I feel that this counts as "any significance", it isn't very satisfactory, because the matrix, as you presented it, does not allow for matrix multiplication.

I think it is a much more useful point of view, to first view $i$,$j$,$k$ as three scalar variables (better denoted by $x$, $y$, $z$), then take the determinant of your matrix and then regard the cross product as the gradient vector this determinant.

Answer (score 0):

You could think of the entries as all being Quaternions, i.e. the matrix is an element of $M_3(\mathbb{H})$. This gives you a genuine way to act on vectors and do matrix multiplication. But you need to be careful about converting between the two different interpretations $i=(1,0,0)\in\mathbb{R}^3$ versus $i\in\mathbb{H}$

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion